# Label text isn't updating after updating its text

Tags: c#

I use this code but it's not working. what am I doing wrong here?

```
private void button_input_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string input = textbox_input.Text;
    string output = label_output.Text;

    output = input.Replace("a", "4");
    output = input.Replace("s", "5");
    output = input.Replace("e", "3");
    output = input.Replace("v", @"\/");
    output = input.Replace("V", @"\/");
    output = input.Replace("m", "|V|");
    output = input.Replace("M", "|V|");

    input = output;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should assign the `output` back to the `textbox`:

```
label_output.Text = output;
```

Reason it doesn't work is that though `string` is a reference type it is immutable. This means that when you use the assignment operator (`=`) a new object is created containing the value. Whenever you apply any changes to the string you are actually creating a new instance with the new value.

Therefore `input` is not a reference to the same string as `textbox_input.Text`. And a change on one does not impact the other. Same applies to `output` and `label_output.Text`.

---

As a side note as `Replace` returns a string you can chain the calls to get a more fluent usage:

```
label_output.Text - textbox_input.Text.Relace("","").Replace("","").....;
```

Comment: Because `input` is a string, not a reference to the `textbox_input.Text` property.

Comment: @GiladGreen "I saw the rest and I'll 'upvote 'you" :)

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer, I'm still a rookie but these things help me a lot!